# BitBucket pipeline breaks when new dependency is added to package.lock

Tags: npm, npm-install, bitbucket-pipelines

Since there is already a saved cache  for *node_modules* when the Pipeline is run, it does not make the `npm install` so new dependencies are not installed. Because of this, while the Pipeline is still running, it suddenly breaks as project does not find the corresponding package.

```
    pipelines:
      custom:
        deploy-staging:
          - step:
              name: install dependencies
              caches:
                - node
              script:
                - npm install
          - step:
              name: deploy to all STAGING themes
              deployment: staging
              caches:
                - node
                - globalnode
              script:
                - npm run deployall -- -t staging
```

How could I fix that?

Comment: please add the error message to your question